# Converting time strings to appropriate format and perform arithmetic over them in Sqllite

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, select, time

I have data in an sqlite database where the timestamps are text in the form 10:15:28 PM  and  9:43:43 PM.

How can I convert them to timestamps?

Comment: What sorts of arithmetics do you plan to do with times _alone_?  Do these times have a date associated with them?

Comment: just time1 - time2. There is no date associated with them. (*edit: There is a date but it is in a another, different column and does not need to be considered for the arithmetic I wish to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, you need to use string functions to convert the values to something the database can understand as a `time`. For these AM/PM dates, one option is to turn the first 8 characters to a `time`, and add 12 hours to values that end with `'PM'`.

```
time(
    substr(mycol, 1, 8), 
    '+' || case when mycol like '%PM' then '12' else '0' end || 'hour'
)
```

From there on, you can use date functions. Say you want the difference between times in `mycol1` and `mycol2` in seconds, then:

```
strftime(
    '%s', 
    time(
        substr(mycol1, 1, 8), 
        '+' || case when mycol1 like '%PM' then '12' else '0' end || 'hour'
    )
) - strftime(
    '%s', 
    time(
        substr(mycol1, 1, 8), 
        '+' || case when mycol1 like '%PM' then '12' else '0' end || 'hour'
    )
)
```